# How can this be possible? (malware autoinstall on chrome)

Tags: malware, chrome, phishing

I have a website, using an ads service (qadabra). Yesterday some users reported me that the ads service sometimes redirects to a site containing malware.

the url is this:

**PLEASE DON'T OPEN IT, IT MAY DAMAGE YOUR PC!!!**

```
http :// download.abocde.com /Flashplay /APX/ IT/ auload.php?installer= Flash_Player_11_for_Other_Browsers &browser_type= KHTML&dualoffer=false
```

(I've already reported it to google)

This website opens an alert that notifies that my video flash player is outdated. If I presso OK it downloads me an executable file automatically (without asking for confirm) and starts the application (again without confirm), installing some sort of adware.

I have chrome 33.0.1750.146 on windows, but it seems to work on all browsers.

How can this be possible? Is it using some kind of bug?

After some research I found that the download link of the malware app is this:

```
filesystem:http:// download.abocde.com/temporary/flashplayer.exe
```

**PLEASE DON'T OPEN IT, IT MAY DAMAGE YOUR PC!!!**

What exactly is `filesystem:`?

Comment: On firefox it does ask to save the file. and the file does not seems that obviously dangerous https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/b8c36f87f4f656d40e6b631d615521fa5c473ec7d089b765319895a7b6240503/analysis/1394546363/

Comment: What OS and version do you use? It might use some local exploit to get out of the sandbox.

Comment: @Wolfer : windows 7 32 bit

Comment: Is it patched to SP1?

Comment: @Wolfer Yes, but I don't think it's a problem with windows...

Comment: Flash Player is a source of exploits. Uninstall it and also shockwave

Answer (score 2):

Given that the malware seems to target flashplayer.exe I'd expect that the malware uses vulnerabilities in Adobe Flash to attack the system rather than a vulnerability in the underlying OS or the browser.

Adobe flash has been shown to be extremely buggy, and it has been widely attacked as a result. Although Adobe have worked hard to fix the bugs there are still plenty of unknown bugs that can be exploited. Also, many people are not updating flash to the latest version, so there are millions of systems out there.

An attacker also has the benefit that flash works on many operating systems, so vulnerability in flash can lead to compromises on Linux and Mac systems as well as Windows systems.

Comment: chrome tab are suppose to be sandboxed. it should not be able to make any modification to the system.

Comment: It doesn't look like it targets flashplayer at all. The url is abod*c*e.com, not adobe.com. It is just trying to look like flashplayer.

Comment: @Kiwy Plugins like Flash are not that easy to sandbox.

Comment: Dunno how, but it seems to use this API https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem